# Как подсчитать и отобразить в консоли кол-во работающих coroutine в asyncio.gather()

Tags: python-3.x, asyncio

Как подсчитать и отобразить в консоли кол-во работающих `coroutine` в `asyncio.gather()`?

На периодической основе нужно отображать в консоле сколько из скольки `coroutines` работает.

```
            tasks = ( self.FetchOHCL(pair, 7*12, '2h', False, 3, 60) for pair in pairs)
            results = await aio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одновременно работает только одна таска, но можно посчитать сколько из них не завершено. На таймер повесить например такую конструкцию:

```
count = len(filter( lambda x: x.done() == False, tasks))
```

Но лучше типовой вариант с wait.

```
pending = tasks

while pending:
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        pending, 
        timeout=10, 
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
    )
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), len(pending), end='\r')
```

Тут принт будет отрабатывать каждые 10 секунд и при завершении каждой задачи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажи, как переделать мои две строчки, чтобы они поддерживали твое последнее решение.

Comment: Просто используй весь кусок вместо gather

Comment: 1) pending = list(tasks)   2) result = [future.result() for future in done][0] Кое что нужно было добавить, чтобы заработало. wait работатет со списком, а результат надо было вытаскивать совеобразным способом.

Answer (score 0):

Обновил код @eri

```
pending = list( tasks )

    while pending:
        done, pending = await aio.wait(
                    pending, 
                    #timeout=30, 
                    return_when=aio.FIRST_COMPLETED
                )
        result = [future.result() for future in done][0]
        resultsList.append(result)
```